# Implementing JmDNS on Android/Multithreading

Tags: android, multithreading, jmdns

I am trying to get JmDNS to work in my android program. I am able to get it to discover the devices I want, but I do not fully understand how to get the information from JmDNS to the object that started the JmDNS task. Here is my code.

```
 protected void browse() {       
      try {
        jmdns = (JmDNSImpl) JmDNS.create();

        jmdns.addServiceListener(type, listener = new ServiceListener() {
            public void serviceResolved(ServiceEvent ev) {

            }
            public void serviceRemoved(ServiceEvent ev) {                   

            }
            public void serviceAdded(ServiceEvent event) {    
                DNSEntry addressEntry = jmdns.getCache().getDNSEntry(name, DNSRecordType.TYPE_A, DNSRecordClass.CLASS_ANY);
                if (addressEntry instanceof DNSRecord) {
                    ServiceInfo cachedAddressInfo = ((DNSRecord) addressEntry).getServiceInfo(true);
                    if (cachedAddressInfo != null) {
                        for (Inet4Address address : cachedAddressInfo.getInet4Addresses()) {
                          //I need to get the address that is here back out of this listener to the main thread
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The problem I am running into is that I have a service manager object that has a instance of a browser object that has the browse method in it. I am unable to get the service manager object access to the address variable. Because JmDNS spawns its own thread when it is created to run its tasks I have tried to use a handler and runnable to send messages with the variable in it but I cant seem to get it right. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to just use the ServiceEvent event object passed into the service added method.  It has all the info you need.

See this example from our open source application

http://code.google.com/p/tunesremote-plus/source/browse/trunk/src/org/tunesremote/LibraryActivity.java

Comment: Yeah that is how it is supposed to work but for some reason JmDNS can't resolve the IP Address of the service type that I want so I actually have to go digging into the JmDNS cache to get the IP Address which it managed to get under a different service type.

Comment: You should not have to do that.  The IP Address should be available in the list .  The event.ServiceInfo object has two methods for getIP4VAddresses() and getIPV6Addresses() that should absolutely work.

Comment: Did you try moving your code to serviceResolved instead of Added?   Added is when it is notified there is a new service, resolved is after it gets all of the info from the Bonjour service like IP address etc.

Comment: I know it should work but it doesn't. There is something wrong with how the service type I want is set up but I am not able to change that. In my code I implemented the cache workaround to solve that issue.

Comment: Did you look at my example.  I send the event on Service Added using a Handler. resultsUpdated.sendMessageDelayed(Message.obtain(resultsUpdated, -1, address), DELAY);  and then later I retrieve it with....   ServiceInfo serviceInfo = getZeroConf().getServiceInfo(TOUCH_ABLE_TYPE, dnsName);

Comment: Thanks Melloware I used your example to get my code to work. I have another question now. In your handler you send the message to your adapter to update your adapter, I would just like to put that message into a ArrayList. If I do that how could another object get notified that a message was added to the ArrayList?

Comment: Hmmm let me think about that.   So in Android you want to use Handlers to send notifications since they deal with the background thread vs main thread issues which is the reason Google added Handlers.  So in your handleMessage(Message msg) method couldn't you just call a method of what you want to execute letting it know there is a new thing in the Arraylist?   So if you had a method called foo that operated on the ArrayList just have the handleMessage method call foo()?

Comment: Do you get JmDNS to always resolve? Half the time it only gets to serviceAdded. It's like it uses up some sockets or something. Any ideas?